# Power Automate Forms points Total Expression

Tags: json, forms, sharepoint, power-automate

Can someone help me? I have a question. I have a Microsoft Forms survey and I am extracting all the responses and putting them in HTML format. However, I would like to get the total points value from the survey and insert it into the HTML. This value does not appear in the dynamic content, and I have been trying to use a variable but so far I have not been able to get the expression right. The expression I have been using is:

```
if(empty(body('Get_response_details')?['responses']), null, first(item()?['responses'])['Points'])
```

And it always returns a value of 0. Does anyone know the correct expression?

```
if(empty(body('Get_response_details')?['responses']), null, first(item()?['responses'])['Points'])
```

Comment: Why is this tagged javafx?

Comment: I'm new to the community and didn't know what to put with 5 tags, sorry

Comment: Is it actually related to JavaFX?

Comment: Do is a favour and show us the JSON from the `Get_response_details` operation? It’s a bit hard to help without it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about points I guess you used the Quiz Template in Microsoft Forms, correct?

As far as I am aware currently the Get Response details action ***does not return*** the points per question or the total points per respondent.

You can try and use the Forms API instead. Hiro has a nice blog about this approach:
https://mofumofupower.hatenablog.com/entry/formsapi

I have found a [GetAggregateQuizData](https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/$metadata) method which should return the averageScore, correctCount per question and an array of responders. It is not exactly what you are looking for, but might still be useful?

Below is an example

```
https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/<tenantid>/users/<userid>/forms('<formid>')/GetAggregateQuizData
```

[image]